# OpenTK / OpenGL attribute names returning gibberish

Tags: c#, opengl, graphics, shader, opentk

I have been working on a renderer using OpenTK. I recently found out that I can't render with more than one shader at a time, so I changed my system around. The problem is that now when all the attributes and uniforms are loaded and put into dictionaries their names are complete gibberish. An example of this gibberish is `" ü\b\aÈy7\aÀNU\u0006"` (which in the shader is called "vPosition"). Sometimes `"GetActivAttrib"` also sneaks in as a ShaderVariable name. I have been stuck on this problem for far too long now so I would appreciate any help.

Here is the code for loading the Shader variables, I am reasonably sure that the problem is somewhere in here:

```
        public static void GetShaderVariables(int shaderProgramID, int selectedShaderID, Dictionary<string, int> AttributeDictionary, Dictionary<string, int> UniformDictionary, Dictionary<string, int> VBODictionary)
    {
        int shaderVariableLocation;

        int LinkStatus;
        GL.GetProgram(shaderProgramID, GetProgramParameterName.LinkStatus, out LinkStatus);
        if (LinkStatus == 0)
        {
            GL.LinkProgram(shaderProgramID); //Linking the program to the graphics card if its not already connected
        }

        GL.GetProgram(shaderProgramID, GetProgramParameterName.LinkStatus, out LinkStatus);
        if (LinkStatus == 1)
        {
            int VBOID;
            #region Storing all the Attributes of the selected Shader
            int shaderVariableAmount;
            GL.GetProgram(shaderProgramID, GetProgramParameterName.ActiveAttributes, out shaderVariableAmount);

            for (int i = 0; i <= shaderVariableAmount; i++)
            {
                GL.GetActiveAttrib(shaderProgramID, i, textBufferSize, out length, out size, out attributeType, shaderVariableStringBuilder);

                string shaderVariableName = shaderVariableStringBuilder.ToString();
                string VBOStringName = shaderVariableName + "VBO";

                shaderVariableLocation = GL.GetAttribLocation(shaderProgramID, shaderVariableName);
                if (shaderVariableLocation == -1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Shader variable doesnt exist");
                    break;
                }

                GL.GenBuffers(1, out VBOID);

                //Stores the values given that the value is not already present in the Dictionary
                if (!AttributeDictionary.ContainsKey(shaderVariableName))
                    AttributeDictionary.Add(shaderVariableName, shaderVariableLocation);

                if (!VBODictionary.ContainsKey(VBOStringName))
                    VBODictionary.Add(VBOStringName, VBOID);
            }
            #endregion

            #region Storing all the Uniforms of the selected Shader
            shaderVariableAmount = 0;
            GL.GetProgram(shaderProgramID, GetProgramParameterName.ActiveUniforms, out shaderVariableAmount);

            for (int i = 0; i <= shaderVariableAmount; i++)
            {
                GL.GetActiveUniform(shaderProgramID, i, textBufferSize, out length, out size, out uniformType, shaderVariableStringBuilder);
                string shaderUniformVarName = shaderVariableStringBuilder.ToString();

                shaderVariableLocation = GL.GetUniformLocation(shaderProgramID, shaderUniformVarName);

                if (!UniformDictionary.ContainsKey(shaderUniformVarName))
                    UniformDictionary.Add(shaderUniformVarName, shaderVariableLocation);
            }
            #endregion
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write(GL.GetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgramID));
            GL.GetError();
            throw new System.ArgumentException("Program failed to link");
        }
    }
```

Here is an example of a vertex shader that im using:

```
#version 330

in vec3 vPosition;
in vec3 vColor;

uniform mat4 modelview;

out vec4 color;



void main()
{
    gl_Position = modelview * vec4(vPosition, 1.0);

    color = vec4(vColor, 0);
}
```

Comment: Read the relative paragraph. https://github.com/luca-piccioni/OpenGL.Net/wiki/GL-%5C-Common-mistakes

Comment: Ive read through it and im going to implement it into my code soon, thank you so much.